# JSON_encode outputs correctly in browser, yet print(json) in Swift outputs 'nil', why?

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode

I have a problem where my JSON is being outputted as NIL in XCode, even though when I test in the browser it reports the correct value.

```
$player1Id = array();
$player1Id = getPlayer1Id($player1name,$communityId);

public function getPlayer1Id($playerName, $communityId)
{

$returnValue = array();

$sql = "SELECT users.id\n"
. "FROM users\n"
. "join community_players\n"
. "on community_players.player_id=users.id \n"
. "WHERE users.user_name = '".$playerName."' AND community_players.community_id = '".$communityId."'";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1 )){
        $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($row)){
            $returnValue = $row['id'];
        }
    }
    return $returnValue;
}

echo json_encode(array($player1Id));
```

If I test in the browser with a set of values in the URL it outputs correctly:

> ["31"]

This is my Swift function:

```
func submit(action: UIAlertAction){
//    print (homePlayerLabel.text!,":",homeTeamLabel.text!,homeGoals,"(",player1result!,") - ", awayPlayerLabel.text!,":",awayTeamLabel.text!,awayGoals,"(",player2result!,")")


    // Send user data to server side

    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/submitScore.php");

    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "communityId=\(communityId!)&player1name=\(homePlayerLabel.text!)&player1team=\(homeTeamLabel.text!)&player1goals=\(homeGoals)&player1result=\(player1result!)&player2name=\(awayPlayerLabel.text!)&player2team=\(awayTeamLabel.text!)&player2goals=\(awayGoals)&player2result=\(player2result!)";

    print (postString)
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in


        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {


                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json)

                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        let returnValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String

                        if( returnValue == "Success")
                        {
                            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);


                            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){(action) in

                                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                            }

                            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        } else {


                            let errorMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                            if(errorMessage != nil)
                            {

                                self.displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: errorMessage!);

                            }

                        }

                    }
                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }



        }

    }

    task.resume()



}
```

Yet when I `print (json)` in Xcode in reports as:

> NIL

Is there something obvious that I am over looking?

Comment: Your response is `Array` of `String` type not `Dictionary` so you need to cast it as `[String]` instead of `[String:Any]`

Comment: i've changed the line to - let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:String] 

but still NIL

Comment: Check the comment properly i have written `[String]` not `[String:String]`.

Comment: Excellent! That's fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you update a **php to 7.1** i get same problem while update php to 7.1  `try to put mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')` i think it's solve your problem